# What determines the 'from' user when using Graph API for 'Send chatMessage in channel' if the from field isn't specified in the request body?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are setting up an automation to send a message to a  Microsoft Teams channel using an app to integrate with Graph API. We are able to send the message successfully however, we are looking to adjust who the message comes from. Unfortunately we are using an integration that doesn't allow additional fields to be set outside of Teams ID, channel ID, and the message body. Does anyone know how the api determines who the message should come from if it isn't specified in the POST request?

We have attempted updating the owner of the app in Azure but no change. Suspecting it might be the user who authorized the app but we haven't been able to test with the other team.

Comment: It will be the user on behalf of whose the request has been sent. We will confirm again and get back to you.

Comment: I would also love to know if it's possible to change the sender; ideally sending channel messages would work with app-only authorization though.

Comment: It is not possible to change the sender, also please note that you can send messaged to a channel only through delegated context. Application permissions are only supported for migration. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnRqM.png